# How to reorder records / rows in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table, that has three columns: `ID`, `Name` and `ParentID`. Let's consider this structure:

```
ID |   Name   | ParentID
 1     Root       NULL
 2   Parent #1     1
 3   Parent #1     1
 4   Parent #1     1
 5   Parent #1     1
 6   Child  #1     2
 7   Child  #1     2
 8   Child  #1     3
 9   Child  #1     4
 10  Child  #1     5
 11  Child  #1     5
```

After reordering the rows by a user, the JavaScript on the client-side will send an array with the new order of the rows by their IDs. For example, it can be `[4, 10, 2, 3, 11, 1]`.

What query/queries should I use so that I could change the order of the rows in my MySQL table? I want to get something like this:

```
ID |   Name   | ParentID
 1     Root       NULL
 9   Child  #1     4
 5   Parent #1     1
 4   Parent #1     1
 3   Parent #1     1
 6   Child  #1     2
 7   Child  #1     2
 8   Child  #1     3
 2   Parent #1     1
 10  Child  #1     5
 11  Child  #1     5
```

Comment: take extra colum named as priority and at all time ajax fire update your priority colum,retrive data order by priority colum

Comment: I don't understand the order of your second list. Can you explain it a bit further? Why is the one with ID=2 almost at the bottom?

Comment: @Priyank57,maybe you should post this as answer else i might do it instead

Comment: @Peanut, i have one more question. If I save order like in second list, the user will see the elements in order, like: 1, 9, 5, 2, etc. or it's no difference between these two lists and data will display always from first to last ID? Thanks.

Comment: @NikosM, please post this as answer. You'll really help me.

Comment: [@Priyank57 and Umair](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29794176/3591273) gave the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view, you can't do it without having an extra column `order`

You will have to create a new column `order` for this purpose.

Then update the table as array is passed.

```
foreach($passed_array as $order => $val){
 $q = "Update table SET  `order` = $order WHERE ID = $val";
 // run query here
}
```

**EDIT**

And when displaying data at frontend, select query will be like

```
"SELECT * FROM table `Order` BY `order` ASC"
```

Comment: Please tell me one more thing: if I save order like in second list, the user will see the elements in order, like: 1, 9, 5, 2, etc. or it's no difference between these two lists and data will display always from first to last ID? Thanks.

Comment: @TurakVladyslav see edits .... 

Whenever you are displaying data anywhere, add `order by order_column` in your query

Comment: @TurakVladyslav will accept my answer if it really helped you

Answer (score 0):

I think You should create new database column (`weight` for example, INTEGER type) which will specify Your row order. It should be the most optimal solution.